# Magento 1.x - General error: 1813 Tablespace exists (Google Cloud SQL)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, magento-1.4

I am using Magento 1.x on Google Cloud SQL for years. Yesterday this error appeared while I was trying to reindex catalog_product_price index:

`` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1813 Tablespace '`myproductiondb`.`catalog_product_index_price_idx`' exists. in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234 ``

I have tried to get rid of a tablespace using:

`DROP TABLESPACE catalog_product_index_price_idx Engine=InnoDB;`

Command runs successfully, yet the error 1813 appears again when I try to reindex prices.

Any hints?

Comment: UPDATE: Now I get ```ERROR 1529 (HY000): Failed to drop TABLESPACE catalog_product_index_price_idx``` when trying to DROP TABLESPACE

Comment: UPDATE: Recreating the database helped.

Comment: If you are not facing the issue anymore I'd suggest you to post an answer.

Comment: @DanielOcando I've tried! :) My answer was deleted via review 4 days ago by pretzelhammer, con, Michael, Owen Kelvin. This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @jhavrda I suggest you add the answer again and accept it as soon as possible. I recommend you are as descriptive as possible about the issue and how you solved it in order to prevent this from happening again. I do agree with you that it shouldn't have happened in the first place though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found "proper" solution. So I've dumped original database, created new database and imported data from original one there. I've changed the scripts to connect to new database and everything works now.